# How can i get time of async function execution?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I need to do some actions if my http requests lasts more than 1 sec (But not stop it, so i can't use duration property)
How is this possible in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `Timer` from `dart:async`:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Future<String> fetchData() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  return 'data';
}

Future<void> main() async {
  Timer timer;
  timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => print("Timer expired!"));
  final data = await fetchData();
  timer.cancel();
  print(data);
}
```